# How to get object API name and Fields API Names from sObject?

Tags: apex, dynamic-apex

I am writing generic code for all object triggers to execute same logic for all objects.

```
global class IsPrimaryUpdate extends AbstractTriggerContext{
public string objecttype;
Map<ID, SObject> parentOpps = new Map<ID, SObject>();
Set<Id> CurrentObjectid = new Set<Id>();

Set<Id> Opportunityid = new Set<Id>();
Set<Id> Opportunityiddel = new Set<Id>();
Set<Id> OpportunityMOid = new Set<Id>();
List<Sobject> OMO = new List<Sobject>();
global override void afterUpdate(List<sobject>newList,List<sObject>oldList,Map<Id,sObject>newMap,Map<Id,sObject>oldMap){
    //override for before insert logic
    for(SObject sObj : newList){
        if(sObj.get('Primary__c') == true){
            objecttype=string.valueof(sObj);
            Object Parentobject = sObj.get('Primary__c');
            Object Currentobject = sObj;
            OpportunityMOid.add(sObj.id);
            system.debug('+++Parentobject  '+Parentobject);
            system.debug('+++Currentobject  '+objecttype);
        }
    }
   
}

// String query = 'Select id,'+Parentobject+'from'+Currentobject+'';
// OMO = [select id, ];
 }
```

[image]

I am getting sObject with all fields as shown above. Now I need to get the API names of sObject and Fields to query and update records.

How to get API names?

the below logic I am trying to get for all objects

```
 Set<Id> Opportunityid = new Set<Id>();
Set<Id> OpportunityMOid = new Set<Id>();

if(trigger.isafter && (trigger.isinsert || trigger.isupdate) ){
for(Opportunity_Market__c d : trigger.new){
if(d.Primary__c == true){
    Opportunityid.add(d.Opportunities__c);
    OpportunityMOid.add(d.id);
   }
 }
}


OMO = [SELECT id,Primary__c FROM Opportunity_Market_Offering__c 
  WHERE Opportunities__c  IN:Opportunityid AND Primary__c =true AND Id 
 NOT IN:OpportunityMOid];

for(Opportunity_Market__c mo : OMO ){

IF(mo.Primary__c == true){
mo.Primary__c = false
OMOlist.add(mo);
  }

update OMOlist;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get the `SObjectType` from an `Id` via the [getObjectType()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.202.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_id.htm?search_text=primitive) method. Then the API name of the object is `String.valueOf(type)`.

You can then go deeper using describe calls on both the [SObject](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.214.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject_describe.htm) and its [fields](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_fields_describe.htm) starting from the `SObjectType` token.

Answer (score 0):

First, although it's not the source of your problem, or the subject of your question... you should refrain from coding like this directly in your trigger. So, to simplify your trigger:

```
trigger OpportunityMarketingOffering on Opportunity_Market_Offering__c (after insert, after update) {
    OpportunityMarketOfferingTriggerHandler.handlerAfterTriggers(Trigger.oldMap, Trigger.newMap);
}
```

Add some conditions to check the before/after etc. and insert/update as you need. Then pass the data into a trigger handler type class. This will make it more directly testable.

Next, the trigger handler class could look something like this (I don't have your data structure so it might not be exact...)

```
public class OpportunityMarketOfferingTriggerHandler {

    public static void handlerAfterTriggers(Map<Id, Opportunity_Market_Offering__c> oldOmoMap, Map<Id, Opportunity_Market_Offering__c> newOmoMap) {
        Set<Id> oppIds = new Set<Id>();
        Set<Id> omoIds = new Set<Id>();
        for (Opportunity_Market_Offering__c omo : newOmoMap) {
            if (omo.Primary__c) {
                omoIds.add(omo.Id);
                oppIds.add(omo.Opportunities__c);
            }
        }
        
        // Remove Primary flag for all opportunity market offerings related to the opportunities
        // associated with the updated batch of opprtunity market offerings
        List<Opportunity_Market_Offering__c> omos = [SELECT Id, Primary__c 
                                                        FROM Opportunity_Market_Offering__c
                                                        WHERE Opportunities__c  IN :oppIds 
                                                            AND Primary__c = true 
                                                            AND Id NOT IN :omoIds];
        if (omos.size() == 0) {
            return;
        }
        
        for (Opportunity_Market_Offering__c omo : omos) {
            omo.Primary__c = false;
        }
        update omos;
    }
 
}
```

I've renamed some of the variables you used, as they are confusing (both you and me!). If I understood what you wanted correctly, you wanted to update the Primary__c flag to false on all the Opportunity_Market_Offering__c records related to opportunities that are referenced in the updated batch of Opportunity_Market_Offerings__c.

One other things I would change... the Lookup field "Opportunities" on your Opportunity_Market_Offering__c should be singular, not plural. i.e. Opportunity__c and not Opportunities__c

Further advice, name your Set/List variables to have pluralised names. If it is a set of Ids, indicate that it holds Ids in the name rather than having to refer back to the declaration.

Comment: Hi @Dan, Thanks for your response. Actually, I need two fields to use in the query. and I am not getting how to write the dynamic query like "SELECT id,Primary__c FROM Opportunity_Market___c 
   WHERE Opportunities__c  IN:Opportunityid AND Primary__c =true AND Id 
 NOT IN:OpportunityMOid"  I need to get list of objects through this Query and update them

Comment: I am trying to query records by using this query --> String query = 'select id, Primary__c from'+Objectname;     List<sObject> objectrecords = (List<sObject>)Database.query(query). But i am getting error --> unexpected token id, Primary__c

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. But the code you supplied will concatenate the objectname directly after 'from', so you will end up with 'SELECT Id, Primary__c FROMsomevalue' rather than 'SELECT Id, Primary__c FROM somevalue'

Comment: Also, in your original code, this line: Object Parentobject = sObj.get('Primary__c'); looks like it is expecting to get an Id from the Primary__c field. You should type and name it as Id parentObjectId = sObj.get('Primary__c');

Comment: ok stirng query is fine @Dan, I need to make use of that query and get List<sObject> and update them with Primary = Flase if they are true. Not sure how to get list of records. Trying to use List<sObject> objectrecords = (List<sObject>)Database.query(query) but getting unexpected id, Primary

Comment: I have mentioned logic for a single object in my question. I need that to make generic

Comment: I'll update my answer to reflect the edited question...

Comment: p.s. in response to the need to get it working generically for multiple Object types... get it working for one first and then make it generic once you know it works. This would generally involve changing the notation from referencing Opportunity_Market_Offering__c type to being SObject and changing field notation from record.Primary__c to be (Boolean)record.get('Primary__c') and finally the queries would need to be Database.query(queryString) but again... get it working for one first and then improve.